# ORA-31186 Xml data too large

Tags: xml, oracle

I encountered an oracle sql error **ORA-31186: Document contains too many nodes** 
when  i try to do select/update/delete from CLOB field that contains very large xml date. I searched around it say need to reduce size of the nodes, is it mean i need to reduce the size of my xml data? If so this is not possible because this is not controlled by us. Any alternatives other than that?

There are 2 conditions:

1) Cannot change the CLOB to XMLType.

2) Cannot reduce the document size.

Example of my query:

```
update table1
set xmlfield = deletexml(xmltype(xmlfield), '//Item[@code="00000002"]').getclobval()
where dbms_lob.compare(xmlfield, empty_clob()) != 0
and xmlexists('//Item[@code="00000002"]' passing xmltype(xmlfield));
```

Comment: Have you tried storing the data in an XMLTYPE column and work on that?

Comment: nope, for me no point doing that because my vendor wont change to XMLTYPE, but i tried the above query on small size xml data in CLOB.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using (including patch level)? How big is the document that errors? Also, do you still see the error if you use the full path to the `Item` nodes, rather than `//Item`?

Answer (score 0):

set:

event="31153 trace name context forever, level 4096"

in init.ora, it will increase limit from 64K to 4M nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in the Oracle Forum: https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4338278/ora-31186-document-contains-too-many-nodes

The problem occurs when relative XPaths are used. When I changed them to absolute paths it worked again.